# jquery scroll effect with a twist

Tags: jquery

I wish to scroll down a bit say 20px then scroll to the top. I have done many trials n errors but unable to implement this effect. My code so far is this:

```
$( "#moveToTop" ).on("click", function() {

        var n = $(document).height() - 20;
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: n}, 1000); // scroll down only 20px but it scrolls all the way down!
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 1000); //then scroll to the top of the page
        return false;

    });
```

**EDIT:**
if i subtract say 20 from document height using var n = $(document).height() - 20; it still scrolls all the way down, even if i add 20 still the same, I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured, I should use window as reference add 20 to wherever the window's scrollTop position is:

```
var n = $(window).scrollTop()+20;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting n to be the document height so it will scroll all the way down...

Comment: i know but if i subtract say 20 from document height using var n = $(document).height() - 20; it still scrolls all the way down, even if i add 20 still the same, I don't know what to do